# change cell background of jquery datatable based on content

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am new to datatables - http://datatables.net/ - . I am in trouble to find an example how I could change the background color of a cell based on its position and content.

Something like this worked for me except that the highlighting of the selected row is now 
'overcolored' in the cells which have changed background color. If I could get the class name of the row in the fnRowCallback then I could handle it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback 
   $("#example tbody").click(function(event) {

      $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function() {
         $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
      });
      (event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
   });


   oTable = $('#example').dataTable({

      "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {

         $(nRow).children().each(function(index, td) {

            if (index == 6) {

               if ($(td).html() === "pending") {
                  $(td).css("background-color", "#078DC6");
               } else if ($(td).html() === "rendering") {
                  $(td).css("background-color", "#FFDE00");
               } else if ($(td).html() === "success") {
                  $(td).css("background-color", "#06B33A");
               } else if ($(td).html() === "failure") {
                  $(td).css("background-color", "#FF3229");
               } else {
                  $(td).css("background-color", "#FF3229");
               }
            }
         });
         return nRow;
      },
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   });
});
```

Comment: We're probably going to need at least an idea of something you specifically want. Can you give us some examples?

Comment: I have something like the below.  I would like to set the background of the cells of the 6th columns based on the content of the cell, e.g. if the content is "A" then I would like to set the background to red. 
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
 } );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('table:last tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').
  css("background-color", "#cccccc");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works, I can change the background color, but unfortunately I am not sure in which datatables callback I could get the cell content and how.

Answer (score 7):

I know the question was already answered, but I thought I would share how I was able to apply "conditional formatting" of sorts to various cells, in the following way:

First, I added a class to each column during my datatables initialization:

```
"aoColumns": [{
                "mDataProp": "serial",
                "sClass": "serial"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "us",
                "sClass": "us"
            }...],
```

Then, I created an addFormat() function that was called each redraw (I had to do it this way because I have a live table that updates in realtime):

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) { addFormat(); },
```

In the addFormat function, I essentially defined all of my formatting rules, via CSS classes.  I used a [jQuery :contains extension](https://gist.github.com/461488) in order to apply very specific rules with regular expressions and such.  My selectors for these rules would be `td` and whatever class I had assigned to a column during datatables initialization:

```
 $("td.us:containsRegex(/^[xtfv]$/)").addClass("s4 queue");
```

That worked very well for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can change background color of cell dynamically respective of cell value by

```
{"mData": "index", "sClass": "center" ,"fnRender": function(obj) {
                                              var index  = obj.aData.index;
                                              var isActive  = obj.aData.isActivated;
                                              if(isActive == true){
                                                  obj.oSettings.aoColumns[obj.iDataColumn].sClass = "greenBackground"
                                              }else{
                                                  obj.oSettings.aoColumns[obj.iDataColumn].sClass = "yellowBackground"
                                              }
                                              return index;
                                          } },
```

Comment: This worked great but I had to change:  obj.oSettings.aoColumns[obj.iDataColumn].sClass = "greenBackground" 
to:  obj.settings.aoColumns[obj.iDataColumn].sClass = "greenBackground"

Comment: i want to do something similar. add css i get from code and save it in property to other property.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but something like this should give you an idea:

```
// Change i-th row j-th column
var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tr');
var columns = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
jQuery( columns[j] ).css("background-color", "#cccccc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to conditionally style the cells via `createdCell`, using [DataTables 1.10+ syntax](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell).

```
"columnDefs": [
{
        "targets": [6],
        "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            var color;
            switch(cellData) {
            case "pending":
                color = '#078DC6';
                break;
            case "success":
                color = '#FFDE00';
                break;
            case "failure":
                color = '#06B33A';
                break;
            default:
                color = '#FF3229';
                break;
            }
            $(td).css('background',color);
        }
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. data[3] means column 4 of the row we're looking at (remember, arrays in javascript are zero-based, that is they start numbering at zero). But when we want to change the cell background, we use the .eq(3) syntax.

```
"createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
    if ( data[3] == "pending" ) {
        $('td', row).eq(3).css('background-color', '#078DC6');
    }
    if ( data[3] == "rendering") {
        $('td', row).eq(3).css('background-color', '#FFDE00');
    }

}
```